# Unix time stamp conversion is different in Mysql and Oracle

Tags: mysql, oracle

Unix time stamp conversion giving tow different result in mysql and oracle

```
select FROM_UNIXTIME(1387444958) from dual;
```

Output :2013-12-19 10:22:38

```
select to_char(to_date('01/01/1970 00:00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')+ (1387444958/86400),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')from dual;
```

output: 2013-12-19 09:22:38

Can anyone please help me in getting same timestamp from oracle as I am getting in MySql.

Comment: Where is the oracle server located? In a country with effective DST?

Comment: Looks like one of your databases is running British Summer Time (or whatever daylight saving variant you apply in your local)  rather than UTC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unix timestamp is seconds from `1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC` which is actually `1970-01-01 01:00:00` in your local timezone (or the timezone where your MySQL server is located). Looks like `FROM_UNIXTIME` takes this into account.

For Oracle you can use this function:

```
FUNCTION UnixTime2Timestamp(UnixTime IN NUMBER) RETURN TIMESTAMP IS
BEGIN
    RETURN (TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' + UnixTime * INTERVAL '1' SECOND) AT LOCAL;
END UnixTime2Timestamp;
```

I assume if you like to get UTC time in MySQL then you have to run

```
select 
   CONVERT_TZ(FROM_UNIXTIME(1387444958),'{your local timezone}','UTC') 
from dual;
```

Comment: Why not `INTERVAL UnixTime SECOND`?

Comment: @SalmanA, It must be a literal, a variable is not possible. `NUMTODSINTERVAL(UnixTime , 'second')` would also work.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit adding interval is solving purpose but i just want to know the reason why there is difference in Timestamp in two DB.

Comment: The key is `AT LOCAL`. It converts the UTC time to your current sessiontimezone. `FROM_UNIXTIME` does this operation internally.